# How can I extract fields from a CSV file in Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

I want to extract a particular fields from a csv file (830k records) and store into hash. Is there any fast and easy way to do in Perl with out using any external methods?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174061/whats-the-best-way-to-read-a-huge-csv-file-using-perl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV_XS). It's fast, moderately flexible, and extremely well-tested. The answer to many of these questions is something on CPAN. Why spend the time to make something not as good as what a lot of people have already perfected and tested?

If you don't want to use external modules, which is a silly objection, look at the code in Text::CSV_XS and do that. I'm constantly surprised that people think that even though they think they can't use a module they won't use a known and tested solution as example code for the same task.

Comment: Note: Not using modules may be an external requirement or limitation of the given environment that joe has to conform to.

Comment: Note: if you can write code, you can install modules. It's an easy thing to explain to business people that you can get it better, cheaper, faster that way. "But I want to build a house without any tools!"

Comment: We are already having so many modules to lot of jobs . So limitation is i cant use any external modules. But here in this case . i guess that would b fine to use. Thanks Brian

Answer (score -1):

See also this [code fragment](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=182908) taken from  [The Perl Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135/) which is a great book in itself for Perl solutions to common problems

Comment: I am sorry for having linked to an apparently pirated copy of the book: the author used to have the code parts online in the past, and I didn't doublecheck the source when I put the link in. Now I have found a better source for the same code.

Answer (score -1):

assuming normal csv (ie, no embedded commas), to get 2nd field for example

```
 $ perl -F"," -lane 'print $F[1];' file
```

Answer (score -1):

using split command would do the job I guess. (guessing columns are separated by commas and no commas present in fields)

```
    while (my $line = <INPUTFILE>){
    @columns= split ('<field_separator>',$line);  #field separator is ","
    }
```

and then from elements of the "column" array you can construct whatever hash you like.

Comment: wondering why I got down vote. Is there anything wrong with my example?